# Insert horizontal line in text int TextView

Tags: android, textview

[image] I have a plenty of lines to display in a single TextView . I get the text from database and then display it. So I want to build the database with entries and horizontal lines in it. When I copy paste them. Only words get pasted and horizontal lines don't appear. I want to insert some horizontal lines at some points of the line like

Hello

---

Hi I am fine

---

There should be a divider like line that can be inserted at places I want . Are there any escape sequences?  But it should be done in TextView text.
Is there any trick to do it? I tried copy pasting the text with line from word but it only copies the text and not the line . Are there any ways to do it like using the horizontal tag in html?? Any help is highly appreciable..

Comment: I added a xml file code ... have a look on it ... May be it'll help you

Answer (score 1):

try below code

```
 <View  android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"/>
```

Comment: I have the textView inside a scrollView. I am taking up text from database and then it will be displayed in TextView. So is there any way to store text with horizontal lines in database itself..

Comment: instead of store horizontal line in database,inflate one layout that contains both textview and line,and assign the text from database to textview.And add inflated layout to your scrollview

Comment: The texts are very long. Hundreds of lines. The thing is I have some \n in my text for every line and I want them to be replaced by horizontal lines. Any escape sequence for it? or else I can store the database with lines but I can't copy paste the lines. I posted the output i need

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do some css inherited in the TextView:

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<span style="border....">Hello</span>"));
```

Edit:

```
String dynamicText = "textGenerated";
String message = "<span style='border-bottom:1px solid'>" + dynamicText + "</span>";

myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(message));
```

Comment: I am taking up a text from database and then displaying it in a TextView. So I want to do it dynamically..

Comment: I tried it but it takes up all the blank spaces. I will post the output of the code as image

Comment: இந்த அத்தியாயத்தின் முதல் வசனத்தில் குரைஷ் என்ற சொல் இடம் பெற்றிருப்பதால் இந்த அத்தியாயத்திற்கு இந்தப் பெயர் சூட்டப்பட்டது. அளவற்ற அருளாளனும், நிகரற்ற அன்புடையோனுமாகிய அல்லாஹ்வின் பெயரால் . 
b . <br> .
1, 2, 3. குரைஷிகளை மகிழ்வித்ததற்காகவும், குளிர் மற்றும் கோடை காலப் பயணங்களில் அவர்களை மகிழ்வித்ததற்காகவும் இந்த ஆலயத்தின்(33) இறைவனை அவர்கள் வணங்கட்டும்.(26) 
b <br>
4. பசியின் போது அவர்களுக்கு அவன் உணவளித்தான்.(463) பயத்திலிருந்து அவர்களுக்கு அபயமளித்தான்.(34)
b <br> .Here every b should be replaced by a horizontal line.

Comment: Are there any functions by which all the occurences of a particular character are replaced by a html tag . In my case a function to replace every b by <hr> tag at runtime will do the trick i think.

Comment: <hr> tag is not working in android.. br tag works. if <hr> tag works then it will solve the trick

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hello" >
    </TextView>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="2dp"
                  android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                  android:padding="5dp">
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hi I am Fine" >


    </TextView>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="2dp"
                  android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                  android:padding="5dp">
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I take up the text from database . It has hundreds of lines where for every line break I want to add a horizontal line. Your code works good for static views. But I take up a dynamic text where all  \n should be replaced by line.

Comment: write the code... than try to resolve your query but mention all the things in question ..

Comment: A TextView within a scroll view. The text is taken from database and then displayed in the Textview. So for every \n I need it to be replaced by horizontal line.. or else I have to store the text with horizontal line in the database. Any escape sequence for horizontal line like <hr> tag?

Comment: No just a static database from which I take up the text. In some lines I want to add a horizontal line.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39471/discussion-between-a-m-and-user2610955)

Answer (score 0):

Add this layout below to your layout XML:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I posted the output as an image. Every new line should be replaced by a horizontal line. I take up text from database so there should be a runtime java code to replace a character with a html tag..

Comment: then make this linear layout in your java code and add in your main layout